# Checkboxes dont work on Salesforce mobile

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, pdf, salesforce-mobile-app

when I visualize a VisualForce page rendered as PDF on the Salesforce mobile application the image of the checkboxes appears with a black background.
I used the following two versions of markup, but neither worked:

1. `<img src="https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/img/checkbox_checked.gif" style="background-color:white;"/>`
2. `<img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" style="background-color: white;"/>`

Comment: There's a good chance the PDF rendering engine cannot handle transparency in GIF files or it defaults the alpha layer to black. I would consider setting the background to white in the image itself. Additionally, the rendering engine for PDFs in Salesforce is fairly old (by web standards), I would also try `background: #ffffff;` to make sure it's not the attribute of `background-color` that is giving you issues.

Comment: @nbrown thanks for your answer it works on desktop!

Comment: @nbrown i tried with [background: #ffffff; ]  it still doesn't work!!

Comment: Like I said, changing the background is guaranteed to work even if it is a heavy handed solution.

Comment: @nbrown it still doesn't work!

Comment: You changed the GIF file itself to white and it still shows as black on mobile?

Comment: @nbrown how can i modify a standard salesforce image?

Comment: Download it, change it, upload it as a static resource.